# pop-up banners can not be closed

Tags: jquery

I wrote the code for five pop-up banners, first two can be closed by click "X", but others can not. Can anyone check the code for me? Where should I modify? Thanks.

I have five ids for these banners: `#closeadv`, `#closeadv2`, `#closeadv3`, `#closeadv4`, `#closeadv5`

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#closeadv").click(function() {
    $("#hovertree_float_layer").fadeOut("slow");
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    console.log("hovertree_float_layer: " + $("#hovertree_float_layer").width() + " window: " + $(window).width());
    var left = ($(window).width() - $("#hovertree_float_layer").width()) / 2 + "px";
    $("#hovertree_float_layer").css("left", left);
  });

  $("#closeadv2").click(function() {
    $("#hovertree_float_layer2").fadeOut("slow");
  });

  if ($(window).width() <= 414)
    $("#hovertree_float_layer2").css("width", "125px");
  else if ($(window).width() > 414 && $(window).width() <= 768)
    $("#hovertree_float_layer2").css("width", "200px");
  else
    $("#hovertree_float_layer2").css("width", "auto");

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 414)
      $("#hovertree_float_layer2").css("width", "125px");
    else if ($(window).width() > 414 && $(window).width() <= 768)
      $("#hovertree_float_layer2").css("width", "200px");
    else
      $("#hovertree_float_layer2").css("width", "auto");
  });
});

function showDiscount() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $("#hovertree_float_layer").fadeIn("slow");
  });
}

function showDiscount2() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $("#hovertree_float_layer2").fadeIn("slow");
  });
}

function showDiscount3() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $("#hovertree_float_layer3").fadeIn("slow");
  });
};

function setposotion() {
  console.log("hovertree_float_layer: " + $("#hovertree_float_layer").width() + " window: " + $(window).width());
  var left = ($(window).width() - $("#hovertree_float_layer").width()) / 2 + "px";
  $("#hovertree_float_layer").css("left", left);
}
```

Comment: Hard to say the reason for the problem without seeing a working example, but it sounds like this could be an event delegation problem.

Comment: Also note that you should really look in to using CSS media queries to amend styles as the window size changes. JS is not the ideal solution for this.

Comment: Can you provide with the html as well? A working https://jsfiddle.net/ would be great.